# jq: select top two level of the object

Tags: json, object, jq, depth

I have some json data that looks like:

```json
{
    "a1": {
        "b1": {
            "c1": {...},
            "c2": [...]
        },
        "b2": {
            "c3": {...},
            "c4": [...]
        }
    },
    "a2": {
        "b3": {
            "c5": {...},
            "c6": [...]
        },
        "b4": {
            "c7": {...},
            "c8": [...]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to:

```json
{
    "a1": {
        "b1": {},
        "b2": {}
    },
    "a2": {
        "b3": {},
        "b4": {}
    }
}
```

Note that `b`s are empty objects. I can get a list of `b`s as arrays:

```bash
cat testjq.json | jq '. | map_values(keys)'
```

But can't figure out how to map it to objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set all items on second level to an empty object, use:

```bash
jq '.[][] = {}' some.json
```

```json
{
  "a1": {
    "b1": {},
    "b2": {}
  },
  "a2": {
    "b3": {},
    "b4": {}
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6BPL98nYdnv)

Note: `map_values` is [defined](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L33) as `def map_values(f): .[] |= f;`, so `.[][] = {}` is effectively the same as `map_values(map_values({}))`.